If a bountied question is closed as a duplicate, allow the bounty to be awarded to an answer on the duplicate
A recent change means that bountied questions can be closed. Bountied questions can/should result in getting more views, as that's the whole idea of the bounty; you are promoting your question to the community. As a result of "more eyes" seeing the question, this can mean that questions that should have been closed now can be (they aren't immune any more), and some of these bountied questions will be closed as a duplicate.
When a user who bountied a question has their question closed, as a duplicate, and they agree with the closure the bounty has served the correct purpose; the user got the answer they were looking for at the cost of their reputation. They cannot, however, then give that reputation to the user who answered on the duplicate question. I'm proposing that should a question be closed, as a duplicate, the bounty user should have the option of giving that bounty to an answer on the duplicate. Of course, there's no requirement to, just like normal. I also don't think that half the bounty should be given if the author doesn't choose to apply the bounty; the bounty must be explicitly given or the reputation is just lost.
At the moment, if the user did want to now award reputation to an answer on the duplicate target, they would have to create a second bounty on the other question, with the intent of awarding it to an existing answer; therefore having to "pay" addition reputation for an answer already received. Also, as highlighted in this question, even with the question  closed, the site continues to prompt the user to award the bounty, even though they can't (as there's no answers on their question); the ability to award to the duplicate question would cause those prompts to be less confusing.
There are likely some nuances that need to be considered; this is just outlining general idea.

Thank the duped question's answer. Thank the duped question. Thank the person who found the duped question. Thank the bounty that brought the person in. Thank the person who put the bounty on. Thank the question itself for being the reason for the bounty. The you yourself for creating the question in the first place.

I generally agree with this request but certain edge cases should be handled properly. For example normally we can't post a bounty on the same question without doubling the reputation offered, but if this is implemented naively there's a chance for an abuse vector where people deliberately post duplicates, award a bounty on them and then close them as duplicate to transfer reputation around.

Yep, definitely going to be some nuances, as I allude to, @AbdulAzizBarkat . I think that certain concerns, and additional ideas, would likely go well in the answers here. Then the community can also vote on any "endorsements" to the proposal.

Shouldn't the one who closed the question be eligible for the bounty as well? After all, they provided all the answers and often no single answer on a dupe fits perfectly.

I don't think so, @MisterMiyagi . The duplicate system is broken as it is, because users who vote to close as a duplicate aren't "rewarded" for going the Search Engine search for the user, while users who answer obvious canonical duplicates are rewarded for posted "Yet another post that shows the same way to foo the bar." Giving the bounty to the close voter is likely more open to abuse. I'd rather see a solution to VTCing as duplicates as a whole.

If it's someone with mjolnir powers for sure, it'll become quite attractive to pick duplicate targets which are "close enough". If multiple people have to vote to close then it becomes sketchy in a different way. Who gets the cookies? Only the first person who voted to close? Are they divided among them? Ain't nobody got time for that, especially not the company. If you want to have any chance of this being implemented somewhere in the next decade, this needs to be as small and simple as possible.

@Gimby All of these considerations should apply to answers as well. Since they aren’t tailored to the dupe, often multiple apply - which author gets the cookie? Mjolnir wielders also can already link to "close enough" questions that have their own answers.

One of options is to award bounty to user who found duplicate.
I think we need to incentivize people to find duplicates.

There isn't always one user that causes a duplicate closure. Gold badge user, sure, but not for close votes or duplicate flags. Would it be split among them? And wouldn't this be abusable, incentivizing closing bountied questions to take it for themselves? See Gimby's comment

I see how this system can be abused. There are several option to counter it. First one: don't close duplicate on just 3 close votes. Require 3 vote for that specific duplicate link. Gold badge user rare enough not to be a problem.

Though I don't disagree with incentives for correct closure as duplicates, I don't think the voter should get the bounty. Some questions have many answers, and several can be good, so the person with the bounty having to award the most useful answer to them seems the right path. I think that there should be a different solution to incentives to voting as a duplicate, and it shouldn't be unique to bountied questions.

@ThomA bounty exist to incentivize people. Awarding existing answers doesn't make sense, they existed before bounty was created.

@Talex there is an option on bounties to explicitly award existing answers. Awarding an answer that already existed makes a lot of sense.

@talex i tend to agree, but then people don't always make sense.

As an example, see here where I use a bounty to "Reward existing answer".

This is actually a pretty interesting idea; it would lessen the wide gap in reward between closing a bountied question as a duplicate and answering it.

@ipodtouch0218 Doesn’t just about everything you listed apply to the duplicate target answers as well? Often multiple answers are answering a dupe with none tailored to it, and it’s trivial to close with a target containing one’s own answers.

there must be more incentive on finding duplicates (and better tools to do it). it's a thankless job, so then few users bother finding duplicates. some users even just post a barely disguised variation of an existing answer on the new question, because that gains them some rep. if this gamified web site really wanted to discourage that type of rep farming by duplication, the game mechanics need adjustment.
